# Hw to specify minimum value for module options in Spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

I need to specify a module option to be greater than 0.  I know how to do a range, but how do I specify only the minimum value in a Spring XD java file?

```
    @Range(min=0,max=??????)
    public int getNumber() 
    {
        return this.num;
    }
```

Where can I find all possible annotations for module options?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `assertion` to check if the num greater zero.

Something like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-module-spi/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/module/options/mixins/ScriptMixin.java#L89)?